# Detect no.of Button clicks Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button

Is there a way to detect the no.of times a button is clicked in Matlab Gui? Am new to this, so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Increase a counter in the button's callback function?

Comment: but that counter has to be global right? Or can I add it as handles property? @LuisMendo

Comment: Yes, you can use object properties for that. See for example http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102591-what-is-the-difference-between-application-data-guidata-and-userdata-in-matlab

Comment: am new to this, so not able to understand from the given link. do you mind giving it as an answer @LuisMendo ? Sry for asing

Comment: I've written an answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. This uses the button's `'UserData'` property to hold the counter. The old syntax (pre-R2014b) is used for getting and setting properties:

```
h = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'Push me'); %// create button
set(h, 'UserData', 0); %// initiallize counter
set(h, 'callback', 'set(gcbo,''UserData'',get(gcbo,''UserData'')+1)'); %// increase counter
```

Now click several times on the button, and get the number of clicks with

```
get(h, 'Userdata')
```